# Python/Gtk starting multiple AppIndicator instances

Tags: python, multithreading, ubuntu, gtk, appindicator

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Python and Ubuntu. Full code is on https://github.com/bluppfisk/coinprice-indicator/tree/multipletickers

I'm adjusting a cryptocoin price ticker, which uses libappindicator to show up in the taskbar in Ubuntu, to be able to run multiple instances of itself.

However, it looks like the system can't tell the various notification items apart, and tries to overwrite them rather than add another. Error:

> libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to register object on path
>   '/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/Coin_Price_indicator': An object is
>   already exported for the interface org.kde.StatusNotifierItem at
>   /org/ayatana/NotificationItem/Coin_Price_indicator

I thought creating a new instance of the Indicator class (which starts the NotificationItem) should automatically do this. In addition, I multithreaded them and started the main Gtk thread after starting the threads:

```
for cp_instance in cp_instances:
    ++counter
    settings = cp_instance['exchange'] + ':' + cp_instance['asset_pair'] + ':' + str(cp_instance['refresh'])
    indicator = Indicator(config, 'indicator' + str(counter), counter, config, settings)
    indicators.append(indicator)

for indicator in indicators:
    indicator.start()
    indicator.join()

Gtk.main()
```

Indicator.py

```
class Indicator(object):
    def __init__(self, config, settings=None):
        self.config = config

        self.settings = Settings(settings)
        self.refresh_frequency = self.settings.refresh()
        self.active_exchange = self.settings.exchange()

        icon = self.config['project_root'] + '/resources/icon_32px.png'
        self.indicator = AppIndicator.Indicator.new(self.config['app']['name'], icon,
                                                    AppIndicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.indicator.set_label("syncing", "$888.88")

        self.exchanges = None
```

Comment: Can probably do without the multithreading. I assume the culprit is in the multiple instances of NotificationItem

Comment: It's difficult to tell what the code snippet does (we have no idea what the variables are and the Indicator() constructor just looks fishy -- what's the method signature supposed to be?)

Comment: added code snippet for indicator, hope that helps figuring it out.

Comment: I just realised that changing the first argument in the Indicator.new() method  may be the solution. Will need to wait until tonight before I can try it out though.

Comment: uh yes that was it. feeling stupid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with `AppIndicator.Indicator.new()`. Running multiple instances would always receive the same name and therefore take up each other's space. Changing the first argument for every instance run is the solution.